Impute for missing value
I'm trying to fill the missing value using simpleimputer but this message shows when I tried to run the code:
enter image description here
I used this code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.impute
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import impute
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

file_path_3 = 'C:\\Users\\s.almalki\\Desktop\\Thesis\\Program Accreditation Decisions.xlsx'
all_Program = pd.read_excel(file_path_3, sheet_name='all Program')    


column = "Service Type"
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
all_Program[column] = imputer.fit_transform(all_Program[[column]])


would it possibly be that you are doing a double index into all_Program when using fit_transform in which case it should just be fit_transform(all_Program[column])
